# Info-Center and kded4 show different versions

Tags: kde, versions, system-info

I've followed [this hint](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/452812-which-kde-version-i-am-using?s=2b609f44cdeda2148864cf0cbb079ec0&p=2278874#post2278874) to get the local KDE version out of `kded4 --version` and it shows

```
Qt: 4.8.7
KDE Development Platform: 4.14.16
KDE Daemon: 4.14.16
```

But the Info-Center ([as suggested here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109626/how-do-i-know-my-kde-version)) do show different versions - and probably the right ones.

[image: Screenshot]

How can that happen? My first and maybe naive guess is, that *kded4* shows actually its own version:

```
kdelibs-bin amd64 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3.1 [167 kB]
```

Comment: Is this happening after updating? If yes, is it happening even after restart?

Comment: @jarleih was right, the problem is the probably old package kdelibs-bin. It also does not come with KDE 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

KDE Neon is based on KDE 5; what Info-Center is showing are the version numbers for KDE 5.
Along the way you have installed a program depending on KDE 4 that has of course different version numbers for qt,...

Comment: That is correct. The program in question is the `kdelibs-bin` package, which is not installed with KDE Neon/5.